# C# Equivalent of adodb recordsets

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am converting a VB6 windows application to C# using VS2008, V3.5.  I have a SQL Server 2000 database I use for data storage and retrieval.  One table holds a single record that is of type Int and is used for generating a quote number, ie, 123456.  In VB6 I do the following:

```
OpenDBCon
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT idx From tblQuoteIdx", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
Select Case rst.BOF
Case False
    rst.MoveFirst
        Me.txtRef = rst!idx
        tID = rst!idx + 1
    OKToContinue = True
Case False
    'Do something
End Select

If OKToContinue = True Then
  Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
  rst.Open "update tblQuoteIdx set idx = '" & tID & "' ", cn, adOpenDynamic, 
    adLockPessimistic
End If
CloseDBCon
```

In C# I currently am doing this:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = Vars.connstring;
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("Select idx from tblQuoteIdx", conn);
        Int32 tt = (Int32)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
        Int32 tt2 = tt++;
        SqlCommand sqlComm2 = new SqlCommand("Update tblQuoteIdx set " +
         "idx = " + tt2    + "", conn);
        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Unfortunately I find now without a cursor lock of "adLockPessimistic" when several people hit the record at the same time multiple instances of the same index number can show up.  If anyone could either explain how to use an ADODB.Recordset in C# for this specific purpose and or use record locks so as to lock the db record when needed, OR a better way within the .Net framework and C# principals to accomplish the same thing, I would be greatful.  Many thanks in advance.

Noel

Comment: Have you looked into ADO.NET?

Comment: Wrap it in a transaction

Comment: If I'm reading your post right, you're trying to avoid different records having the same value in the ID field.  Most data-storage products support that by default.  There are many ways to accomplish it if yours doesn't... auto-incrementing new IDs by 1 during a create failure (via a try-catch-finally block), enforce different ID stepping chains for different user segments, construct a performant service queuing data submissions with responsibility for data validation and subsequent submission, but wrapping it with the transaction that RC mentioned is likely simplest.

Comment: Regardless of what solution you approach you really should wrap your entire data-store interaction in a *try-catch-finally block*... **try** for opening the connection & writing data (when it's ready) -- **catch** to handle potential exceptions -- **finally** to close your connections and .Dispose any applicable objects.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will find this article useful:
[Pessimistic locking in ado.net](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pessimistic-locking-solves-adonet-concurrency-problems/1049842)
Basically you will need to wrap everything in a transaction that applies a lock on the records as soon as editing starts. This way no other method will be able to edit the values until the lock is released.